# Wait and Resume?

Tags: java, android, gwt

In Android, I would `startActivtyForResult`, a new activity would start. When that new activity was finished, it would `setResult` and trigger `onActivityResult` in the first activity.

What is the equivalent to that in plain Java? I want to call a new uibinder owner class, in that panel once I have a result, I want to come back to the first class and display the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mechanism is called a **Callback**. You can implement your desired functionality using Observer desing pattern in Java.

[Observer design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)